# If I flip a coin and get 1 billion heads in a row, is tails more likely in the next flip?

Tags: statistics

If I flip a coin and get 1 billion heads in a row, is tails more likely in the next flip?

Is it 50% or does the poisson distribution say it would be a good to bet on tails?

Comment: What do we know about the coin?  Are we told ahead of time that the coin is fair?  Are we told that each flip is conducted independently of one another?  The answer for a **fair** coin is that the coin "has no memory of past events" and that regardless of what you have seen flipped the next flip will still again be fair and have a 50% chance of landing on either side.  In *reality* if you flip a coin a billion times and get a billion heads, you'd stop and look at both sides and check to see if it was in fact a trick coin with no tails side to begin with.

Comment: If you flip a coin and get 1 billion heads in a row, I can tell you with a high degree of certainty that 1) you will be very tired and bored and old, 2) you must be flipping a two headed coin.

Comment: Relevant article on wikipedia: [gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy).

Comment: Coins do not have memory, nor spiritual effects, or the converse is true?

Comment: No one can predict the future. Probability is just an illusion.

Comment: That might make a mildly interesting question: Mr. Trustworthy chooses either a double-headed coin or a fair coin with probability 50% of each, then flips the coin 11 times.  If the first 10 flips were a head, what is the probability the 11th flip is also a head?

Comment: Sounds like an application of Bayesian probability.

Comment: "No one can predict the future. Probability is just an illusion"- Probability does not claim to predict the future so the second sentence does not follow from the first.

Comment: @DanielSchepler the way you've phrased it (*each coin was equally likely to have been picked*), the answer would be $0.5\times 0.5 + 0.5 = 0.75=\frac{3}{4}$, remembering again that coinflips are independent and past flips don't influence future flips, so the probability would have been the same as for the first flip.  @ Tob, its instead a direct application of total probability.  The related bayes' theorem question would have been to ask "what is the probability that the coin flipped was actually the fair coin instead of the fake doubleheaded coin"

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry, what I actually meant was that the choice of which coin to flip is made once and then the same coin is flipped 11 times, not that the coin to flip is chosen independently for each flip.

Comment: That is already the interpretation I had and the answer remains the same. If you don't believe me, run the calculations yourself.  It hinges on the phrase "each coin was equally likely to have been picked (at the beginning)"

Comment: @JMoravitz My calculation with conditional probability is: suppose $F$ is the event of choosing a fair coin, $H_{10}$ is the event of the first ten flips being heads, $H_{11}$ is the event of the eleventh flip being heads.  Then $P(H_{11} | H_{10}) = P(H_{11} \cap H_{10}) / P(H_{10}) = (P(F \cap H_{11} \cap H_{10}) + P(\lnot F \cap H_{11} \cap H_{10})) / (P(F \cap H_{10}) + P(\lnot F \cap H_{10}) = (1/2^{12} + 1/2) / (1/2^{11} + 1/2) = \frac{2049}{2050}$.

Comment: If anything, it would mean that heads is more probable. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic "gambler's paradox" or "gambler's fallacy" problem, and its solution depends entirely upon what is known prior to the beginning of the game.  If you know for certain (i.e., with probability = 1.0) that the coin is fair ($p_{tails} = 1/2$), then the probability of a head on the next roll is the same as the probability of tails, and both equal 0.5--regardless of the extraordinary run of tails.  If, however, you do not know the coin's probability (or "bias"), you either have (or must assume) some model of its possible values, parameterized by some unknown or unknowns.  For instance, you might model the probability as a Gaussian centered on $p = 1/2$ with some unknown variance within a range.  Or a uniform distribution with unknown upper and lower limits.  Or any of a number of distributions.

Then, using Bayesian inference, you *learn* or *estimate* the parameters of your probability model with each coin flip experiment.  The more data, the more accurately you can estimate the unknown parameters.

Then, after your 1,000,000,000 flips, you calculate the posterior probability of getting a head or tail on the next flip based on this learned model, which will generally include some uncertainty.  (In practice, though, 1,000,000,000 flips will be enough to specify your model parameters very accurately so the uncertainty will be very small!)

For your specific example, you might assume no prior information about the probability of tails, and model it as a uniform distribution between a lower value, $p_l$, and and upper value, $p_u$, and start with $p_l = 0$ and $p_u = 1$.  (This is called the *Laplace prior* over $p$.)  After your first role, you can infer that $p_u > 0$.  (After all, it cannot be exactly equal to 0, given that you got a tails on the first roll.)

Note, though:  that even if you learn your *model* very accurately, that does not mean you can predict the result of the *coin toss* very accurately.  For instance, you might learn that your model is .4999999999 < p < .50000000001.  (Very accurate model!)  Nevertheless, your predictions of the coin outcome on flip 1,000,000,0001 will be wrong very nearly 50% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

If the coin is fair, then heads and tails have equal chance. Take your pick.

If you were able to flip the coin $1$ billion times in a row, then safe to bet on heads, probably biased.

Answer (score 0):

If you flip a coin $1,000,000,001$ times, it is true that more likely that one flip will be a tails out of the billion and one(**a1**)than no flips being tails(**a2**). However, it is equally likely that the first billion will be heads and the next tails(**b1**) and all flips will be heads (**b2**)because we're saying what the first billion are, and the increased chance comes from the uncertainty of which toss it happens on.
$$\operatorname{(a1)}\frac{1,000,000,001\choose1}{2^{1,000,000,001}}<\frac{1}{2^{1,000,000,001}}\operatorname{(a2)}$$
$$\operatorname{(b1)}\frac{1}{2^{1,000,000,000}}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2^{1,000,000,001}}\operatorname{(b2)}$$
Now if you're playing in real life, and manage to flip a billion heads in a row, guess heads because most likely there's an extremely influential bias occurring making the coin favor heads.